Find a way to prove that this space is not locally $1$-euclidean
Let
$$X_1=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3, x=0, (y-2)^2+z^2=1\}$$
$$X_2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3, x=0, y^2+z^2=9\}$$
and consider the space $X$ generated by a complete rotation around the $z$ axis of $X_1\cup X_2$. Establish whether $X$ is locally $1$-euclidean or not.
The space is a sphere with a torus inside that it is tangent to the equator.
My idea is to use the fact that $X$ is connected, so the dimension is uniform. Easily, I see that every point admits an open neighbourhood homeomorfic to the $2$-dimensional disk, so $X$ is locally $2$-euclidean. Therefore, $X$ cannot be locally $1$-euclidean.
Beyond the formal details, is this a correct way?

$X$ is not locally $2$-Euclidean simply because there is at least one poinhaving a neighborhood homeomorphic to $\Bbb R^2$. What would be more interesting would be to prove that (contrarily to your "Easily, I see that...") it is not locally $2$-Euclidean.

Ok, and so if I prove that $X$ is not locally $2$-euclidean , then I can conclude because $X$ is connected?

Sorry, typo at the beginning of my comment: I meant "$X$
is not locally 1-Euclidean simply because...". Connectedness is useless.

Ok, but finding a point  $p$ that has got a neighborhood homeomorfic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ allows me to assert that $p$ has got no neighborhood homeomorfic to the line? In other words, if a space is locally $1$-euclidean, then it cannot be locally $m$-euclidean with $m\ne 1$, is it right?

Your 1st sentence is right: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain. Your 2nd sentence is a corollary but is not useful here, as $X$ is neither locally $1$-Euclidean nor locally $2$-Euclidean.

So, for example, I can take the north pole of the sphere, this point has got a neighborhood in $X$ homeomorfic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and for what we have said before, it cannot admit a neighborhood homeomorfic to the line. Does it make sense?

Yes, perfect. But again, a more interesting and challenging question is to prove that $X$ is not locally $2$-Euclidean.

Perfect thanks! I was thinking about it and I think that the points that could cause problems are those of the circumference where the sphere and torus intersect, is this a good claim?

Yes, prove it..

I think that what I obtain intersecting a $3$-dimensional ball and $X$ cannot be homeomorfic to the $2$-dimensional disk because if I remove the arc that connect the piece of torus and the piece of sphere, than I obtain a disconnected space but if I remove the image under an homeomorfism of that arc to the $2$-dimensional disk, then it still connected

No, if you remove the diameter of a disk, it becomes disconnected. But only in two pieces, not four...

Ok, but the neighborhood has got 4 connected components, the disk remains connected or has got two connected components (in case I remove the diameter as you said). So the homeomorfism cannot exists in any case. Am I right?

I agree.${}{}{}$

Thanks for the very enlightening discussion!
